# How to manipulate response status code from a Rails Controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a classic controller action. Have a look at the MARK. I need to set the status code to 200 for the response. Background: swfupload an ajax file upload solution seems to send data in a wrong format.

I tried response.headers['Status'] = 200, response.status 200, render :json => 'data', :status => 200. But the response's status code doesn't change.

```
def create
  if params[:Filedata]
    @medium = Medium.new(:swf_uploaded_data => params[:Filedata])
  else
    @medium = Medium.new(params[:medium])
  end

  respond_to do |format|      
    if @medium.save  
      format.html { redirect_to(@medium, :notice => 'Medium was successfully created.'); }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @medium, :status => :created, :location => @medium; }        
      MARK
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @medium.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status code can only be declared within the return commands like render, redirect_to .... and will affect to this return command, there is no way to set the code for all the responses

For `format.html { redirect_to(@medium, :notice => 'Medium was successfully created.'); }` since is a redirection the code will be a 3XX and you can't change it or the redirection won't work

For `format.xml  { render :xml => @medium, :status => :created, :location => @medium; }` you are declaring the status as created, this means for rails that the code is 201, for making it a 200 change it for:

`format.xml  { render :xml => @medium, :status => :ok, :location => @medium; }`

Comment: link to docs:   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render     "The :status Option"    can simply use `render :status => 500`

Answer (score 0):

What format is the AJAX call expecting in response? You're only responding to HTML and XML, so if it's expecting JavaScript or JSON, that might be a problem.

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but I've never seen a condition inside the `respond_to` block like you've shown. Usually it's like this:

```
if @medium.save
  respond_to { |format| ... }
else
  respond_to { |format| ... }
end
```

I'm also not clear what the "MARK" is supposed to be.